# How to make a correct password encryption in django users?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I would like to learn how to use JSON web-token authorization in Django.

I am a newby in django, so I find several tutorials and followed them EXACTLY step by step.

I have user model in my app:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)
```

Also I have a serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            user = User(**validated_data)
            user.username = validated_data.get('username')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user
```

please, take a look at `user.set_password(password)` here.

Then I have a api endpoint for creation a token, another endpoint for handling POST request for my users. Nothing special here.

The problem is that JWT authorization works not as I expected:

**Problem description:**

I. Encryption of user password.

I send JSON to POST method of my api endpoint for user creation

**Expected result:** test user is created and password is stored in encrypted way

pbkdf2_sha256$150000$mE9jeTnJdBds$X6VtRY0HKM4o4by4PzWNxtgKb8NL1mZg4W5M+y4Ohb0=

**Actual result:** test user is created and password is stored in non-encrypted way.

123456

II. Obtain token issue

Pre-conditions:

1. I create a superuser via manage.py createsuperuser
2. I create a testuser via my api endpoint.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Obtain token for superuser. Call endpoint with TokenObtainPairView.as_view(). As expected I successfully get a token
2. Obtain token for testuser.

**Result**: Call the same endpoint for test user ends with a 401 error "Unable to log in with provided credentials".

**Expected result**: obtain token for testuser.

I tried to use several libraries for JWT as djangorestframework-jwt, and djangorestframework_simplejwt (please, don't recommend tutorials, this is useless, I tried almost all of them)

I figured out the problem, that the password in user table for my superuser is encrypted, but for my simple test user - not.

So I am at 99% sure that the real problem is that the password is not encrypted. Please take a look, that my serializer calls a `set_password()` method. I expect it should encrypt my password

Could you please give me some help in these issues?

If it helps, I can provide source codes, used tutorials and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving your instance in your serializer's `create` method which is not right, because the `perform_create` method in the view is responsible for that. What you should be doing is creating an instance and returning it. Also you should make a password and pass it to `create` as argument. You don't set it because you have not created an instance yet. This would be a correct way of doing what you intend.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
def create(self, validated_data):
            password = make_password(validated_data.pop('password'))
            return User.objects.create(password=password, **validated_data)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. The password encryption now fixed and as I expected JWT authorization starts working for test users